# how to use xargs with sed for file path rename?

Tags: linux, shell, sed, arguments

I want replace file path some word, but sed not work.

for example:

```
echo "./src/main/java/com/abc" |xargs -i echo "mv {} `sed 's/abc/def/' <<< {}`"
```

the actual output is:

```
mv ./src/main/java/com/abc ./src/main/java/com/abc
```

not I expected:

```
mv ./src/main/java/com/abc ./src/main/java/com/def
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Another (simplest) way, using [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/727288/12574):

```
$ rename -n 's@/abc$@/def@' ./src/main/java/com/abc
rename(./src/main/java/com/abc, ./src/main/java/com/def)
```

Remove `-n` (aka `dry-run`) when the output looks satisfactory.

#### Another way, using shel concatenation:

```
$ echo -n mv "./src/main/java/com/abc "; echo $(echo "./src/main/java/com/abc" | sed 's/abc/def/')
```

### Output

```
mv ./src/main/java/com/abc ./src/main/java/com/def
```

Comment: I solved it with `echo "./src/main/java/com/abc" |sed 'p;s/abc/def/' |xargs echo mv`, But why `echo "./src/main/java/com/abc" |xargs -i echo "mv {} `sed 's/abc/def/' <<< {}`"` not work?